Dumb replacement for cites command
I need a command that can serve me as a drop-in replacement for the \cites command of biblatex when required to use bibtex/natbib due to template restrictions.
To do so, I want all optional arguments passed to the \cites command simply be ignored, and have the mandatory arguments passed to \cite.
So I need a command that takes, e.g., \cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}[6][7]{key8}{key9} and issues \cite{key3,key5,key8,key9}
I took some inspiration from this answer, but am clueless how to get the result of \cites put into \cite rather than working with the individual keys.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% dummy cite command for the MWE
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]}

% WIP ... Command that replaces \cites
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\cites}{oom}{#3\next@cites}
\NewDocumentCommand{\next@cites}{oog}{%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{,#3\next@cites}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \cites{key1}
    
    \cites[1]{key2}
    
    \cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}
    
    \cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}[6][7]{key8}{key9}

\end{document}


To process a command of the form
\cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}[6][7]{key8}{key9} while ignoring optional parameters and issue \cite{key3,key5,key8,key9} use
\NewDocumentCommand{\cites}{oomomoomm}{\cite{#3,#5,#8,#9}}. You need to check that this matches the parameters that you intend to use \cite.

@PeterGrill the \cites command has a variable number of arguments (as demonstrated in the MWE in this question), so that wouldn't work.

You can define a command that holds the cite keys in the first call to \cites, and append to that command in calls to \next@cites. Adding to a command can be done with the built-in (LaTeX2e) command \g@addto@macro. Then by adding a True case to \IfNoValue you can call the cite command with the full list there.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% dummy cite command for the MWE
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{[#1]}

% WIP ... Command that replaces \cites
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\cites}{oom}{\gdef\mykeys{#3}\next@cites}
\NewDocumentCommand{\next@cites}{oog}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\cite{\mykeys}}{\g@addto@macro\mykeys{, #3}\next@cites}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \cites{key1}
    
    \cites[1]{key2}
    
    \cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}
    
    \cites[1][2]{key3}[4]{key5}[6][7]{key8}{key9}

\end{document}

Result:

